# Is there a real power series with radius of convergence 1 that converges uniformly on (−1,1)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

> Is there a real power series with radius of convergence $1$ that converges uniformly on $(−1,1)$?

I am guessing the answer is yes, if we can construct a function with power series such that it converges on the radius of convergence, but I do not know any examples of this. Help someone?

Comment: Hint: Pick any power series which converge on $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes take $$\sum _ {n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^2}$$

The uniform part can be checked with [M-test Weiestrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test). And the radius with $\limsup \sqrt[n]{ n^2 }=1$

Comment: bravo, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Lost1 Glad I could help:)